# Adding Angular CLI to an existing project

Tags: angular

I'm trying to find out how can I exactly add/generate an angular application to my existing project.

It's an eCommerce which has this structure:
[image]

if I use `ng generate` it just prompts me with this

```
Error: This command is not available when running the Angular CLI outside a workspace.
```

otherwise `ng new` let me create a new angular application, would be correct drag and drop everything in my existing webApp? Should I put everything into the /src/.../resources folder? since it's where I put all my html and css files?

Answer (score 0):

Run `angular` and `JAVA` on two separate ports/servers, this will ensure both can be scaled up separately if needed.

For angular just create a folder called client at the root of the project to contain the angular code.

After you create the `client` folder, just go inside it and run `ng new farmaciaOnline` then a folder will get created and then you can start your frontend development!